# Use the definition of derivative to prove $\lim_{x\to 0}\ln(x+1)/x =1$

Tags: limits, derivatives

How would I use the definition of derivative to prove 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 1$$

I got to $$\frac{\frac{\ln(1+x+h)}{(x+h)} - \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}{h}$$ but have no idea where to go from here.

On another site I found someones answer where they stated the following:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x) - \ln(1+0)}{x-0} 
= [\ln(1+x)]'\rvert_x = 0
$$
but I am unsure why the $x$ in the $x-0$ is removed. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Let $f(x)=\ln x$.  Then the limit is equal to $f^{\prime}(1)$ by the definition of the derivative (with x in place of h).

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(x+1)-\ln 1}{x}=(\ln t)'|_{t=1}=1$$

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} &= \\
 &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x) \quad\quad\quad\text{(Using log rules:)}\\
 &= \lim_{x\to 0} \ln\left((1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right) \\
 &= \lim_{x\to 0} \ln\left((1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}})^{\frac{1}{x}}\right) \\
 &= \begin{bmatrix}b = \frac{1}{x} \\ 
   x \to 0 \implies b \to \infty
   \end{bmatrix} \\
 &= \lim_{b\to \infty} \ln\left((1+\frac{1}{b})^{b}\right) \\
 &= \ln\left(\lim_{b\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{b})^{b}\right) \\
 &= \ln(e) \\
 &= 1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

from the definition: 
$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

so if I say that $f(x)=ln(1+x)$ we know that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$
$$
1=f'(0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{x}
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{ln(x+1)}{x}$$

remember that $f(0)=ln(1)=0$